# jquery Prevent to call function

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="content">
    <div style="background:url(...jpg) no-repeat #01AEF0;" class="slide-small">
       <div><strong>Title</strong></div>
        <div class="read_more"><a class="t_10" href="http://example.com/">Read More</a></div>
     </div> 
</div>
```

When I click on the `div` that has a `class="content"` my code calls function. When I click on Read More the function is called and after that the new page opens. I need not to call the function, only open the `href`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.read_more a').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

`events` like `click` bubble to **ancestor elements**. To prevent that event *bubble* further than your `a` element ... read this: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.content').click(function(e){
   if(e.target === this) {
        // Only then call your function
   }
});
```